# required page redirect based on success response on asp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am new to development currently working on one development task on asp and c#, from the website when ever user filled the form and click submit it will trigger the webhook post method on backend and i am capturing the response also but the problem is its displaying directly on the webpage instead i want redirect to different webpage and say custom message based on the response its like when ever i get success i want to redirect page and say your request hasbeen successfully submitted else your request hasbeen failed

```
below is the code 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace azuremfareset
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected async void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                lblmsg.Text = "submitting....";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtemail.Text))
                {
                    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "emailid", txtemail.Text}
                };

                    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
                    var content = new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    string url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webhook_url"];
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                    lblmsg.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "enter emailid";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that `redirects to a different website`. Are you looking for that particular line of code ?

Comment: Are you just asking how to perform a redirect in ASP.NET?  What did you find when you searched for that information on your favorite search engine?

Comment: Yes..apologies i am new to development i need that line of code

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a page using `Response.Redirect(page.aspx);`

This redirects a request to a new URL and specifies the new URL.

You will need to add the namespace System.Web. Example: `using System.Web`

You can find the Microsoft Documentation on it [by clicking this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8)